# "no observations from which to fit a model" error

Tags: r, tree

I have a data frame with 125 variables.  There are quite a lot of NAs because the data is from a survey which had logic in it to present questions only if it made sense based on previous answers.

I am trying to build a classification tree using the "tree" package.  When I try to build a tree

```
t1 <- tree(outcome ~ ., data=surveyData)
```

I get the error `"no observations from which to fit a model"`.

I'm not sure how to interpret this error and haven't found anything on the forums or in the documentation.

I have been trying to build trees with some smaller subsets and that seems to work.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to post a minimal reproducible example, especially as this is a data-specific issue.

Comment: If the error says it has no observations, then probably the first sensible thing to do would be to check and see that what you think is in `surveyData` is actually in there. Number of rows? Column names?

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out.  I had some columns of data that had too many NAs and it made the tree function complain.  I removed those variables and was able to create a tree.

Comment: You should delete the question or post an explanation using a full example and demonstration about how you discovered the way forward as an answer.

Comment: thanks for your comments everyone.  I am new here (as you can tell). I  appreciate the patient explanations of the correct protocol.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem.  I had some columns of data that had too many NAs and it made the tree function complain. I removed those variables and was able to create a tree.

I removed the offending columns and built a tree this way:

```
naCols <- vector(length=125)
for (i in 1:125){ naCols[i]<- sum(is.na(data[,i]))}
subset <- data[,which(naCols < 10)]
myTree <- (outcome ~ ., data=subset)
```

I have a bigger problem of figuring out the best way to handle all of my NAs - but that's a different story.